# Searchable List View

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

So i'm trying to make a searchable list view using a custom array adapter.

I finally got the search working but the results are not exactly accurate.

Its actually a hit and miss kinda thing e.g Searching for Drupal gets me Google Plus, you knw what I saying?

So here's my adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final String[] imageIdUrl;


public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] web, String[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageIdUrl = imageId;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    //find row view
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    //find text
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    //find image
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    //set text
    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    //set image traditional
    //imageView.setImageResource(imageIdUrl[position]);
    //set image with picasso
    Picasso.with(this.context).load(imageIdUrl[position]).into(imageView);
    //return row
    return rowView;
}
}
```

And heres my Main Activity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView list;
EditText editsearch;

String[] web = {
        "Google Plus",
        "Twitter",
        "Windows",
        "Bing",
        "Itunes",
        "Wordpress",
        "Drupal"} ;
String[] imageIdUrl = {
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg",
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg" ,
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg",
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg",
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg",
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg",
        "http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Google_Logo_04.jpg"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, web, imageIdUrl);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
    editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I'll be grately thankful for any help. This is proving to be a major headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code in onTextChanged() method to afterTextChanged() method as below:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    String str=s.toString();
    getSearchItems(str);
}
```

In getSearchItems use the filter properly. I used other way to filter as,

```
public void getSearchItems(String searchText){
    List<Employee> searchList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    List<Employee> employeeList=getEmployeeList();
    if(employeeList2!=null){
        for(Employee e:employeeList){
          if(e.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())){
            searchList.add(e);
          }
        }
    }
    adapter.refresh(searchList);
}
```

Then In adapter use another method refresh() as below:

```
public void refresh(List<Employee> employeeList){
    this.employeeList=employeeList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Actually I used Employee class which contains his name and address, and I made search using employee name. So u change the above code which suits your search.